# Win 7 reboot loop at Mup.sys

Tags: windows-7, boot, 64-bit

Short version:
Homebuilt Win 7 system. No recent SW/HW changes. Suddenly fails to boot even in safe mode, instead getting into a reboot loop while loading (or just after loading?) "Mup.sys". Win 7 repair mode isn't helping.

Long story:
I built this system and it's been smooth sailing for several years. It's running Windows 7, 64-bit.

Last night while watching a video, the screen became a frozen blur of color, and the PC become completely unresponsive. After rebooting I was able to start the video again -- and it made it much further into the movie -- but at some point I lost audio. When I closed the video, I saw the Windows taskbar at the bottom of the screen (the one with the Start menu & etc in it) was gone. Assuming something important had crashed, I attempted to reboot again. I was taken to the "something went wrong" screen, and tried each of Safe Mode (w/ and w/o network), Last Known Good, Start Normally, and each would get as far as Mup.sys and then reboot.

Finally, possibly just by coincidence, one time Windows just started up. I ran a Norton full system virus scan overnight which came up fine...but when I closed Norton the Windows taskbar disappeared again. Since then I haven't been able to get it to boot again.

Last thing I've tried was booting from my Win 7 install disk in recovery mode. Sadly I get:
"This version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the version of Windows you are trying to repair. Try using a recovery disk that is compatible with this version of Windows."

As a quick sanity check, I confirmed that I was using the 64-bit disk, not the 32-bit one...and then even tried from the 32-bit one just to be sure.

I haven't installed any new SW or HW recently that I can think of.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!